drone wifi connection problem
Recently I've purchased an RC drone, which is advertised as being controllable by a smart phone in addition to its remote control. My drone is nothing pro like a DJI and it can probably be considered as a toy drone. The name and model of the drone is Corby CX022 - 2B but I am sure such drones are sold with a different name in every country. The link of the drone is here if you want to check it out (it is in Turkish but the pictures should give an idea):
https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/tr/product/_corby-cx022-2b-zoom-pro-ultimate-smart-drone-1220171.html
I can connect to the drone using its wifi signal. The application that is supposed to be installed on the smart phone is Wifi UAV (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lcfld.fldpublic&hl=en&gl=US). But despite being able to connect to the wifi signal of the drone, I have neither managed to get the camera working nor control the drone through the app (I tried with both a Google Pixel and iPhone 8). It seems like from the app's perspective, the drone is not connected (although I am connected to its wifi signal).
Being a computer engineer, I tried to do some debugging but didn't get very far. I found out that the drone's wifi has DHCP and is assigning my phone the IP address of 192.168.80.2. The IP address of the drone (the gateway) is 192.168.80.1
Some online posts said to disable the mobile data service of the phone, which I did to no avail. Some posts said to statically assign an IP, which didn't make a difference either.
By the way there are numerous apps for such drones. I've tried many of them including ones such as KY FPV: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cooingdv.kyfpv&hl=tr
All of these apps have a very similar interface and I think from all app's perspective I wasn't connected to drone (although from the phone's wifi menu, I was).
I was wondering if the wealth of experience in this forum can perhaps nudge me in the right direction toward the solution of this problem. Any debugging and/or suggestions are very welcome.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xaufohf.rxdrone I experienced the same problem.This app should work.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  In this instance, at the very least you should say what the app is and what it does. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Make sure your phone isn't automatically reconnecting to a preferred wifi network. Then using the static gateway/ip on the phone should work.
